# Gnuplot how plot 3d figures in a style similar to Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, gnuplot

I found gnuplot's 3d figure not very attractive.

Is there a way to product a figure looks like this one:

[image]

The key points are:

1) less density of x and y tics
2) grids
3) tics bars toward outside the figure.

Here is what I have tried (dowwnload the script here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45318932/gnuplot2.plt):

[image]

I know how to manually set x/y tics but I do not want to as it is not a general solution. Unless you can set x and y tics dynamics according to your data.

Can you help me finish the second figure in the style of the first one (matlab)?

Comment: The first picture is a bit misleading as it is for some completely unrelated data. It's better to include a _minimal_ example within the question containing a _specific_ problem. At the moment, I think this question is too broad. Can you narrow it down to something like "How can I do X in gnuplot"?

Comment: To set the tics towards the outside use `set tics out`. As far as I know, you cannot draw vertical grid lines on the x-z and y-z planes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the best I can get, using gnuplot:

[image]

The code is here: https://github.com/mleoking/JavaGnuplotHybrid/blob/master/JavaGnuplotHybrid/src/org/leores/plot/JGnuplotDemo.java

Comment: Can you use gnuplot code instead of Java code in your answer? I'm interested to know how you draw grid lines on the vertical planes (x-z and y-z). Also how you put multiple plots on a 3d plot.